# Put fixed space between two columns in a datalist

Tags: asp.net, html, css, datalist

I'm using a datalist to display images. There are two columns per row but the spacing between the columns is too little. Is there a way to place a fixed spacing between the columns?

```
 <td class ="DLSettings"> 
    <asp:DataList ID="DlReviewImages" runat="server"  
                  RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                  HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <table >
                 <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="tableborder">
             <tr>
                           <td align="center">
                              <a href="" target="_blank" runat="server" id="AImage">
                              <img runat="server" id="ThumbnailReviewImage" width="250" height="200" border="0"/>     </a>
                           </td>
                         </tr>
                      </table>
                   </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
 </td>
```

CSS :

```
.DLSettings{ 
               border-width:1px;    
    border-color:Black;    
    border-style:solid;    
    background-color: #E3E3E3; 
    padding:5px 10px 30px 30px;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

BB

Comment: set you cellpadding to 5 on your table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just use the `CellPadding` property to increase the spacing between columns:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" ...>
```

You don't need either of the tables in your `ItemTemplate` either. They're just taking up space and slowing things down. Try using the `ItemStyle` for alignment instead:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DlReviewImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" CellPadding="5" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">  
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemTemplate>   
          <a href="" target="_blank" runat="server" id="AImage">   
              <img runat="server" id="ThumbnailReviewImage" width="250" height="200" border="0"/>     
          </a>                              
    </ItemTemplate>   
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add padding to the right of the table cells, so in the css...

```
td{ padding-right: 10px; }
```